# psql command is not found in only certain lines in shell scipt

Tags: bash, shell, psql

I have a shell script with a psql command to update a Redshift table. It's worked several times in the original spot in the shell script, but when I copied the command into another line in the script, I got an error saying `psql: command not found`.

Here's some pseudocode of where the `psql` command has and has not worked:

```
#start

if [ -f filename.txt ];
then echo 'first area';
psql #has not worked here
else psql ; #has successfully worked here
fi;

psql # has not worked here
#end
```

I'd just like pointers or suggestions to figure out the behavior of this. Is there any plausible explanation for this to work only in that `else` statement?

Comment: What editor do you use to edit your script?

Comment: I'm using Notepad++. I made sure that EOL conversion is in UNIX/OSX format too

Comment: I would not be surprised if you had invisible characters there and there. I do not know Notepad++ but if it has some feature available to make them visible, you should maybe use it.